# OpenWeather API Image not displaying

Tags: android, bitmap, png

I made an app which can tell the weather when you enter the location .. the API is taken from OpenWeatherMap.org and its displaying the weather .. i wanted to display the icon also i took the icon id and pasted in the link .. the image is not displaying..

```
 try {

                DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

                String city = weatherInput.getText().toString();
                Log.i("City name",city);

                //used to encode the entered input for url.. for example San Fransisco appears in url
                //as San%20Fransisco ... and to enable that we use the encoder...
                String encodedCity = URLEncoder.encode(city,"UTF-8");

                downloadTask.execute("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + encodedCity +
                        "&appid=cd66504ca815ddc1971662a9f2147f84");

                Log.i("Image id",icon);

                ImageDownloader imageDownloader = new ImageDownloader();
                myImage = imageDownloader
                        .execute("http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + icon + ".png").get();
                imageView.setImageBitmap(myImage);

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
```

and here is the ImageDownloader class. **icon is a global variable which i got when i parsed the API with other variables like weather conditions**..

```
 public class ImageDownloader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>{

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {

        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection;

        try {
            url = new URL(urls[0]);
            httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.connect();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Please note that i have two AsyncTask classes in a single Activity so if its causing some error .. i have no idea about it..

Comment: Someone answer please...